# accessing formatted text in select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am formatting the text once an option is selected in select2. It appears as formatted. I want to access the formatted text later. However,when I access using

```
$('#mySel').select2('val') or 
$('#mySel').select2('data').text
```

these only return the original option text.

My formatResults function below

```
function formatResults(state) {

    if (!state.id) return state.text; // optgroup
    var result = "<a style='color:inherit; text-decoration:none;' onclick= 'return     myonclickevent(this);' id= '" + state.id + "' class='"+"ops"+ "'>"
        + operator[state.id] + " ( " + state.text+" )</a>";
    return result;

 }
```

I want the text returned to be in the form "operator(option)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jquery to directly query the select2 element to get the formatting:
     var columnName = $("#mySel").select2("data").text; 
     $('#s2id_mySel').find("#"+columnName).attr('class')

Answer (score 1):

The formatting functions will only be called when Select2 displays data, and they require the original object that Select2 uses internally.

When you call `select2("data")`, you are retrieving the internal object that Select2 is using the represent the data. When you are calling `select2("val")`, you are basically getting the `id` property of these objects, in most cases.

You must take these objects and pass them to your formatting functions manually if you want to use the formatting functions outside of Select2. So instead of calling `$("#mySel").select2("data")`, you would call `formatResults($("#mySel").select2("data"))`.

Comment: Makes sense. The only challenge is that I want some information that's included as a class in the formatting at the time of selection that's not persisted later. I used the approach I have added as an answer below.